# Strange results from fetchAll

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, query

I got some strange behavior in Magento.
I ran raw sql query (`SELECT`) from mangento at first, then from HeidiSQL. And got different results. How can it be? Is there any way to listen to the PDO method `fetchAll` and modify the result? I do not know how to find an observer which can do that.

I'm running the query from magento like that:

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$rows = $read->fetchAll($sql);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it myself. 
Reason was in HeidSQL actually. For some reason it shows all columns in result set, though some of them should be overriden:

[image: heidisql strange results]